# Angular Js Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys i get the error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=loginApp&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

I dont know why but here is my files all in the same folder i think it has something to do with ngRoute not getting implemented correctly in login.html but not sure. You guys dont need to read the css as im preety sure they arent the spot of problem.Thanks for your help!

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Angular Js</title>
  <!-- load Bootstrap and custom style.css -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="login.css">

  <!--Google Font - Work Sans-->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!--Login-->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller = "loginController">

  <div id="container_demo" >
    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="login" class="animate form">
            <form  autocomplete="on">
                <h1>Log in</h1>
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />
                </p>
                <p class="keeplogin">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" />
                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                </p>
                <p class="login button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </p>
                <p class="change_link">
                    Not a member yet ?
                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="register" class="animate form">
            <form autocomplete="on">
                <h1> Sign up </h1>
                <p>
                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                </p>
                <p class="signin button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
                </p>
                <p class="change_link">
                    Already a member ?
                    <a href="#/ToDo" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

login.css:

```
#subscribe,
#login{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 88%;
    padding: 18px 6% 60px 6%;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189,0.8);
    box-shadow:
        0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),
        0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#login{
    z-index: 22;
}
/**** general text styling ****/
#wrapper h1{
    font-size: 48px;
    color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
    padding: 2px 0 10px 0;
    font-family: 'FranchiseRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/** For the moment only webkit supports the background-clip:text; */
#wrapper h1{
    background:
    -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
        rgb(18, 83, 93) ,
        rgb(18, 83, 93) 20px,
        rgb(64, 111, 118) 20px,
        rgb(64, 111, 118) 40px,
        rgb(18, 83, 93) 40px);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

#wrapper h1:after{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background:
        linear-gradient(left,
            rgba(147,184,189,0) 0%,
            rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 20%,
            rgba(147,184,189,1) 53%,
            rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 79%,
            rgba(147,184,189,0) 100%);
}
/**** advanced input styling ****/
/* placeholder */
::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
    color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
    font-style: italic;
}
input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder{
    color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
    font-style: italic;
}
input {
  outline: none;
}
/* all the input except submit and checkbox */
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]){
    width: 92%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 32px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
    box-sizing : content-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.6) inset;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):active,
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):focus{
    border: 1px solid rgba(91, 90, 90, 0.7);
    background: rgba(238, 236, 240, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.9) inset;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontomasCustomRegular';
    src: url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.svg#FontomasCustomRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/** the magic icon trick ! **/
[data-icon]:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'FontomasCustomRegular';
    color: rgb(106, 159, 171);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 30px;
}
/*styling both submit buttons */
#wrapper p.button input{
    width: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(61, 157, 179);
    padding: 8px 5px;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(28, 108, 122);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) inset,
        0px 0px 0px 3px rgb(254, 254, 254),
        0px 5px 3px 3px rgb(210, 210, 210);
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#wrapper p.button input:hover{
    background: rgb(74, 179, 198);
}
#wrapper p.button input:active,
#wrapper p.button input:focus{
    background: rgb(40, 137, 154);
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(12, 76, 87);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}
p.login.button,
p.signin.button{
    text-align: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
/* styling the checkbox "keep me logged in"*/
.keeplogin{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.keeplogin input,
.keeplogin label{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.keeplogin input#loginkeeping{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.keeplogin label{
    width: 80%;
}
p.change_link{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(127, 124, 124);
    left: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 440px;
    padding: 17px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 16px ;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(219, 229, 232);
    border-radius: 0 0  5px 5px;
    background: rgb(225, 234, 235);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
    rgb(247, 247, 247) ,
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 15px,
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 15px,
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 30px,
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 30px
    );
}
#wrapper p.change_link a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(247, 248, 241);
    padding: 2px 6px;
    color: rgb(29, 162, 193);
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(203, 213, 214);
    transition: all 0.4s  linear;
}
#wrapper p.change_link a:hover {
    color: rgb(57, 191, 215);
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgb(74, 179, 198);
}
#wrapper p.change_link a:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
#register{
    z-index: 21;
    opacity: 0;
}#toregister:target ~ #wrapper #register,
#tologin:target ~ #wrapper #login{
    z-index: 22;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}.animate{
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}#toregister:target ~ #wrapper #login,
#tologin:target ~ #wrapper #register{
    animation-name: fadeOutLeftBig;
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Angular Js</title>
  <!-- load Bootstrap and custom style.css -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">




<!--Login-->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller = "ToDoController">

  <h1 style = "text-align:center;" id = "ToDoHeader">Todo List</h1>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder= "What Needs To Be Done?" ng-model = "textValue">
  <a class="button-0" ng-click = "submit()">Submit</a>


  <ul id = "tasks">



  <li  ng-repeat = "messages in toDo">{{messages.textValue}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>







  </body>

</html>




<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> -->
```

main.css:

```
#ToDoHeader{
  font-family : Impact;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999999, 0 2px 0 #888888,
             0 3px 0 #777777, 0 4px 0 #666666,
             0 5px 0 #555555, 0 6px 0 #444444,
             0 7px 0 #333333, 0 8px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
             0 9px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* 16 * 0.0625 = 1px */
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  font-size:100px;
}
#text{
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  left:430px;
  top:40px;
  height:60px;
}
:placeholder-shown {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight:bold;

}
.button-0 {
    position: relative;
    bottom:20px;
    left:920px;
    height:60px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
    /* Animation */
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.button-0:hover,
.button-0:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.button-0:active {
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#tasks{
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
  text-align: left;
  right:50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family : Impact;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["firebase"])

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.js',
      controller: 'loginController',
    })
    .when('/ToDo', {
      template: 'Loged In!'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);



app.controller("ToDoController", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
  function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://todolistt.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.toDo = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.submit = function(){
      if(!($scope.textvalue == ""))
     ref.push({
       'textValue' :$scope.textValue
     })
    }

}
]);










/*
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
  when('/About', {
    templateUrl: 'About.html'
  })
  .otherwise({d
    redirectTo:'/'
  })

})*/
```

**EDIT Problem**

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qy8W3toWMfRqn18WISRp?p=preview) is my Plunk. The problem here is two things, first for some reason i cant start the plunk with login.html and second i cant use app.config for some reason. When ever i take away app.config the todo page becomes good for some reason. Thankyou

Comment: you are using angular.min.js but your in development, swap it to angular.js so you can get comprehensive errors

Comment: Ok @JoeLloyd I will create a plunk in a few seconds so it becomes easier for you guys to identify problem

Comment: Download the **Angular.min.js** and use it locally or make sure that you are using the right version. Also, move the Angular import to be the first to get fetched in your head.

Comment: **Do Not Develop With Angular.min.js** you get cryptic errors that make little sence, the .min is for production.

Answer (score 0):

Your app name in js and view are different, change

from

```
<body ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller = "loginController">
```

to

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller = "loginController">
```

Comment: you need to create jsfiddle or plunk for your issue

Comment: I put a plunk at bottom of question

Answer (score 0):

I changed the AngularJS reference, added JQuery (because Bootstraps needs JQuery), added Angular-route and added `ngRoute` as I said earlier.

**[Working Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0p7oPFdHFQiM84dFjpEy?p=preview)**

These are the tags I added (**in an important order else it doesn't work**):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this in your `main.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["firebase", "ngRoute"]);
```

Comment: I already tried them both but didnt fix issue i edited it so there is a plunk at bottom

Comment: @JohnDoe I edited my answer and now it works perfectly as how you wanted it, I also described what I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Well not only do you have to do what was previously mentioned by Goldenowner and Sajeetharan. You actually need to include the ngroute module to your project.

```
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/e4PsZ0WUpwjY4HH4FFzO

The link in your error message tells you this.